# Difference between net/http/pprof and runtime/pprof

Tags: go, profiling

I have been reading about the profiling here it is explained using [net_http_pprof](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/) and here [runtime_pprof](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/). So, what are difference between these two and which one should be prefer over another. And please don't paste the overview definition from the given links

Answer (score 7):

`net/http/pprof` exposes the pprof profiler data via a web interface.  If you're writing a server-based system, this may be useful since you may not have access to the host.

`runtime/pprof` will write the profiler data to a data file that you can then convert into various image or document types.  If you're writing a system that can't or won't have a web interface, this is probably the one to use.  Either way they expose the same data.